# Selecionando um valor de uma linha/coluna da ListView populada pelo LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview, wpf, linq-to-sql

Através do evento duplo clique preciso puxar um valor de uma linha/coluna em uma ListvView populada pelo LINQ to SQL.

Por exemplo, quando o usuário precisa selecionar um valor de uma linha/coluna dessa ListView, após o evento duplo clique, essa informação iria alimentar uma Textbox com a ID do banco SQL (não o Index da ListView) correspondente a essa linha/coluna clicada.

Vejam de conseguem me ajudar! Por favor!

**Classe que atualiza a Lista..**

```
namespace TRSSystem.AcessoDados

public static List<tabProduto> Consultar_ALL()
        {
            TRSSystemDataClassesDataContext oDB = new TRSSystemDataClassesDataContext();
            List<tabProduto> oProdutos = (from Selecao in oDB.tabProdutos orderby Selecao.Descricao select Selecao).ToList<tabProduto>();
            return oProdutos;

    }
```

**Quando Inicio o formulário WPF...**

```
listView_tabProduto.ItemsSource = TRSSystem.AcessoDados.tabProdutoAcesso.Consultar_ALL();
```

**Evento do Duplo Click...** (NÃO FUNCIONA)

```
private void Select_Item(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {


           txtDescricao.Text = listView_tabProduto.SelectedIndex.ToString(); -------> Não funciona

        }
```

Comment: Queres o ID ou o índice do item selecionado? se for o índice podes fazer usando: `ListView1.SelectedIndex;`

Comment: Estou querendo puxar o ID da linha que o usuário irá clicar na ListView que foi carregado pelo LINQ...

Comment: ListView1.SelectedIndex, consigo pegar a posição na ListView...Porém queria pegar a posição no Banco de Dados (ID), não na ListView...Entende?

Comment: sim entendi. posso ver o código que usa para popular a ListView ?

Comment: sugiro editar o seu post e adicionar o código

Comment: Editado...Dá pra entender?

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que pegar a coluna da linha selecionada:

```
DataRowView linha;
int linhaIndex;

linhaIndex=  listView_tabProduto.SelectedIndex;
linha= listView_tabProduto.Items.GetItemAt(linhaIndex) as DataRowView;
txtDescricao.Text = Convert.ToString(linha["Descricao"]);
```

. Referencia:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0e08f378-dc9d-42f9-b2a5-00414a37ec0e/how-to-get-value-of-selected-item-in-listview?forum=wpf

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/53389)

Comment: Resolvido, é isso?

Comment: Opa agora melhorou! Quando resposta é muita curta ou só tem link ela cai na fila de analises, aquele primeiro comentário é automatico.

Comment: Entendi, Obrigado!

Comment: Ainda não funcionou com o poste anterior...O erro:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TRSSystem.exe

Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Acredito que não está puxando o valor da linha clicada com a coluna "Descricao"...Valor é null...

Alguma outra adequação!?

Att.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite.

Encontrei a solução:

```
    private void Select_Item(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView_tabProduto.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            tabProduto id = (tabProduto)listView_tabProduto.SelectedItem;

            txtDescricao.Text = id.Descricao.ToString();

        }

    }
```

Referencia:
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2138/manipulando-dados-com-wpf-e-linq-to-sql.aspx